# Smarty template array variable print error

Tags: php, arrays, smarty

I have following code in my smarty template.

`{$data.Experience}`

This will return output as follow:

`a:5:{s:4:"from";a:1:{i:1;s:0:"";}s:2:"to";a:1:{i:1;s:0:"";}s:11:"CompanyName";a:1:{i:1;s:0:"";}s:8:"Industry";a:1:{i:1;s:22:"Information Technology";}s:8:"Position";a:1:{i:1;s:0:"";}}`

Can anyone let me know why it is printing serialize array and How can I print every field value in `.tpl` file.

Try with this also:

```
{assign var='decoded' value=$data.Experience|unserialize}
        <br/>
        From: {$decoded.from.1}<br/>
        To: {$decoded.to.1}<br/>
        Industry: {$decoded.Industry.1}<br/>
```

But, nothing is print.

Comment: Whats the output of `{$decoded|debug_print_var}` ?

Comment: Not even an error/warning ? At least you could write a template function or use the {php} block (http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.php.tpl) like so `{php} $tmp = $this->get_template_vars('data'); $this->assign('decoded',unserialize($tmp['Experience'])); {/php}`

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following

```
{assign 'decoded' $data.Experience|unserialize}

{$decoded.from.1}
{$decoded.to.1}
{$decoded.Industry.1}
...
```

tested in smarty 3

Comment: Thanks But, I have Version: `{$smarty.version}` give me `2.6.14`
Is there any other solution for this version.

Comment: Try `{assign var="decoded" value=$data.Experience|unserialize}`

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got answer by myself.

There is a different syntax in Smarty Version 2.x
I have done as follow and its work nice for me.

```
{foreach from=$data.WorkExperience|unserialize key=key item=value}
     <li>{$key|ucfirst}: {$value.1}</li>
{/foreach}
```

I don't know why assigned variable is not worked in Smarty Version 2.x If anybody has answer please post.